# Why are the Weak force states different to the mass eigenstates?

Tags: mass, standard-model, fermions, higgs

On one hand we have the electro-weak interaction doublets $(u,d)$, $(c,s)$, $(e,\nu_e)$, etc. On the other hand, on the Yukawa interaction term that gives mass to fermions we have those same doublets. Is there a fundamental reason why the mass matrix in the yukawa intraction can't be diagnalized in the same basis as the weak interaction doublets?

I know that experimentally one sees that the weak force has a probability of coupling, for example, $u$ and $s$ quarks (CKM Matrix) so one has to change the down-type quarks to a new basis. I'm asking if there is a fundamental explanation... Maybe it is actually impossible to diagonalize all matrices at the some time or something like that.

Comment: All three generations have the same EW quantum numbers. So the gauge couplings and the Yukawa couplings **have no good reason** to couple to the same basis in both sectors; it would be a "scandal" to be explained if they did! Your text certainly discusses that.  Nature can, and does, misalign such couplings.  They are, of course, observed, not understood. It is, in fact, impossible to simultaneously diagonalize both sectors.

Answer (score 0):

your question is 3 years old, but i have a clue on this. The experiments say that CKM is not diagonal, so there is not question on this, the nature says if we have mass matrix diagonal (and that is what we want for give fermions mass) we would have mixing in the coupling with the weak force, the CKM matrix is input in the theory that is from the experiment and stablish all of this, so the answer to your questión is that nature is like this.

The next to ask is why CKM is like that, we do not know theoretically but there is a path to follow, study CKM and all the work around this matrix to have the next clue for: why do we have the mixing or why are there only 3 generations of fermions?

Check this, this will give u more context: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-ckm-matrix.pdf